# gitolite mac don't add new user to authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, mac, gitolite

I installed gitolite and every thing works fine for me as admin. But when I'd like to add add a new user the new user can't connect to the server. After I looked into the file authorized_keys I saw that the new user wasn't added to the file. During the commit of the new public-key I get some workings:

```
WARNING: split conf not set, gl-conf present for 'gitolite-admin'
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 882 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: WARNING: split conf not set, gl-conf present for 'gitolite-admin'        
remote: WARNING: ?? @staff christianwaldmann markwelch        
remote: sh: find: command not found        
remote: sh: find: command not found        
remote: sh: sort: command not found        
remote: sh: find: command not found        
remote: /usr/local/bin/triggers/post-compile/update-gitweb-access-list: line 26: cut: command not found        
remote: /usr/local/bin/triggers/post-compile/update-gitweb-access-list: line 23: grep: command not found        
remote: /usr/local/bin/triggers/post-compile/update-gitweb-access-list: line 26: sort: command not found        
remote: /usr/local/bin/triggers/post-compile/update-gitweb-access-list: line 26: sed: command not found        
remote: sh: find: command not found        
remote: sh: find: command not found
```

How can I fix it that gitolite auto-add the new user to the authorized_keys.

Comment: It seems some commands where not found. Is gitolite chrooted? Are the commands "find", "sed", "grep", "cut" and "sort" available on the normal console?

Comment: I can tip "find" into the terminal (when I logged in as git on the machine directly) without a bash.

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo do you think this problem can be caused because I symlinked the repository folder to an external folder on a NAS (with a higher RAID level for a better data safety) which is mounted over network?

Answer (score 2):

The section "[uncommon errors](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/emergencies.html#ue)" give some possible causes.

> (**Case 1**) you copied a bare repo ("`repo.git`") from another `g3` site (or `g2` with `GL_BIG_CONFIG` on).
>   Then you pushed a change to "`gitolite.conf`" or ran certain server-side commands without adding the repo to the conf.
>
> Conversely, **you removed "repo" from "`gitolite.conf`" but did not remove the actual "`repo.git`" on disk**.
>
> (**Case 2**) This can also happen if you changed something like this

```
repo foo
    ...<some rules>...
```

> to this:

```
@grp = foo
repo @grp
    ...<some rules>...
```

> Also, even running `gitolite setup` will not fix this.

But it all comes done to:

> The root cause is an internal consistency check that I do not wish to disable or subvert.
>   It is there for a reason, and I would prefer a warning that a human can investigate.
>
> If you're sure the reasons are one of the two above, you can either add the repo to the conf file in case 1, or manually remove the gl-conf file from the `repo.git` directory in case 2.
>
> Either way, run gitolite setup afterwards to make sure things are in good shape.

---

In this case, the solution was a complete "reset", as the [OP crashbus](https://serverfault.com/users/133790/crashbus) mentions [in the comments](https://serverfault.com/questions/422446/gitolite-mac-dont-add-new-user-to-authorized-keys/422449#comment452566_422449):

> I solved the problem by deleting the "`git`" user completely from the system and following the tutorial form [**Git "Server" on OS X Lion**](http://www.themacosxserveradmin.com/2012/04/git-server-on-os-x-lion.html).

Comment: I had already found that help page befor I posted my question. Neither case 1 nore case 2 could happend on my server, because It was a new system, I haven't change something in the config except the new entries for the new user (I added him to a new repositorie) and the imported repositories came from gitosis.

Comment: @crashbus gitosis? Maybe the format used during that import is somehow faulty. Did you check https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/convert-gitosis-conf ?

Comment: hmm I only imported the .git bare repositories and added the repositories than per hand in the gitolite config (there were not many).

Comment: @crashbus ok, just checking there. What if you simplify: no repo (beside the `gitolite-admin` one, and you try adding users. Does the issue persists then?

Comment: I removed all repositories but the issue still persists.

Comment: @crashbus ok; and what it you try a manual installation of the latest gitolite V3, as described in https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh (or http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html#req) ? Would the issue still persists?

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting the "git" user completely from the system and following the tutorial form http://www.themacosxserveradmin.com/2012/04/git-server-on-os-x-lion.html. @VonC thanks for your help

Comment: @crashbus Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.