# Git server SSH user authorization failed

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I have been installed gitlabhq on SERVER.

I have issue while cloning repo from client machine. Not work:

```
client> git clone git@my.serv.ip.addr:myrepo.git /tmp/myrepo

client> ssh git@my.serv.ip.addr
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Under server root I can do successfully command.

```
gitserv> sudo -u gitlab -H git clone git@my.ip.add.r:myrepo.git /tmp/myrepo
Start clonnin repo
```

I supposed that it is SSH keys issue, but don't know what to do.

By the way one strange think:

I can't login to ssh server from client machine

```
ssh root@my.serv.ip.addr
Received disconnect from my.serv.ip.add: 2: Too many authentication failures for root
```

But succesfully login from another server.

```
anotherserv> root@my.serv.ip.addr
gitserv>
```

Comment: There was problem in MaxAuthTries /etc/ssh/sshd_config.  But i can't understand why ssh client recheck all private keys

Answer (score 1):

Since GitLabHQ is based on Gitolite, you must make sure that the following work:

```
ssh git@my.serv.ip.addr
```

As long as you don't see a Gitolite answer, any clone won't work.
You need to add a public ssh key to your GitLab profile, and check if `~git/.ssh/authorized_key` is updated:

```
 command="/home/git/bin/gitolite-shell user_email_uuid",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1...Bc5CtLFcg+lTz+ZKKWpf+p5/9ZaR9T/KtpbibnvhQ== username
```

When you see a similar line in `~git/.ssh/authorized_key`, then the ssh request from the client should work.

Comment: I see that in ~git/.ssh/authorized_key ` # gitolite start
command="/home/git/gitolite/src/gitolite-shell gitlab",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa
# gitolite end ` But can't login   ssh git@my.serv.ip.addr

Comment: I can access only throw server root not client machine > ssh git@my.serv.ip.addr and  get ' hello gitlab, this is git@web3 running gitolite3 v3.2-gitlab-patched-0-g2d29cf7 on git 1.7.2.5

                             R W gitolite-admin
'

Comment: client>gitolite-admin.git has been cloned succesfully. But i has a lot of another project. It seem i get migration error.

Comment: @Stepchik you need to see your public key in that `~git/.ssh/authorized_key` file. GitLab should ask Gitolite to update that file once you have entered a public key in your profile *and* have added your account to a project.

Comment: I can clone gitolite-admin.git and nothing more. Gitolite config  WARNING: split conf not set, gl-conf present for 'project1'

Comment: /home/git/.ssh/authorized_key looks normaly

Comment: @Stepchik you can clone the admin repo as `root@my.serv.ip.addr` or as `git@my.serv.ip.addr`? The error message reminds me of http://serverfault.com/a/422449/783, but also http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.gitolite/1075. What is the version of your gitolite, btw?

Comment: Yes i can clone admin repo git@my.serv.ip.addr. I have been changed my gitolite version from 2.to 320

Comment: @Stepchik so does `ssh git@my.serv.ip.addr` works now? Do you see a Gitolite greeting message?